# Reduce gain of emitter follower

Tags: transistors

I need to reduce the gain of an emitter follower circuit to 50%. Can I do this by splitting the emitter resistor into two sections and taking the output from the junction? I am concerned that I will loose the low output impedance characteristic of the circuit if I do this.

Comment: Why not instead halve the *input*?

Comment: How low do you need the output impedance to be ? Maybe you can get away with just using 2 emitter resistors in series. If not, use Wouter's suggestion.

Comment: What output impedance is maximum you can tolerate?

Comment: I need the output impedance to be below 20 ohms. The input is from an electret capsule and I am reluctant to interfere with its parameters. In the case of splitting the emitter resistor, my own thoughts are like this: the O/P impedance at the emitter is 20 Ohms and the output impedance at ground is 0 Ohms, so in between it could hardly be any higher, or could it? I'm using a 1.5 K resistor.

Comment: Does your input have a pull-up resistor? If so, split it in two resistors and couple to the junction.

Comment: Yes it does, that's a good suggestion.I didn't think of it but I suppose that's what stack exchange is all about. Thanks.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Would you care posting an answer about this? This is a good question+answer pair, it doesn't deserve to live on just in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your current circuit looks like this (simplified, DC bias of Q1 omitted)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frKMoW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If so, you can split the mic's load/pullup resistro, the mic won't notice, and the transistor will get half the AC input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fykndJ.png)</sup>

Comment: Yes, this is more or less the circuit. I've done it and it works perfectly. Thanks.